# replacing double space to single space

Tags: c++

How can I replace the double space into single space using C++

ex:

```
"1  2  3  4  5" => "1 2 3 4 5"
```

this is what I`ve done till now:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(myFile);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File Opened ...\n";
        while(myfile.good())
        {
            getline(myfile,line);
            splitLine(line);
            //cout<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"File Not Found ...\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}

void splitLine(string line)
{
    int loc;
    cout<<line<<endl;
    while(loc = line.find(" "))
    {
        cout<<loc<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `line` by reference, otherwise any changes done inside `splitLine` will remain unnoticed. (Alternatively, you could return the updated `line` by value.)

Comment: Also, I don't see how `line.find(" ")` searches four a *double* space? Your example does not contain any double spaces either... maybe you should clarify what you mean with the term "double space".

Comment: @Fred:  The html is only showing up single spaced, but the OP typed two spaces. (edit to see)

Comment: @Jared - Two spaces work just fine in my answer.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? Do you really want to replace *any* chunk of whitespace with a single space, or only exactly `"  "` (two spaces)? And **why**?

Comment: Do not use `while myfile.good()` to control the loop. It does not do what you want. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.4 (and the next section) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In while loop of splitLines code, use this code.

```
  while((loc = line.find("  ")) != std::string::npos) //Two spaces here
  {
       line.replace(loc,2," "); //Single space in quotes
  }
  cout << line << endl;
```

Thats it. I haven't tried it out, let me know if it works.

And as fred pointed out, use pass by reference in splitLines function. The above solution is sub-normal and is O(n^2) complexity. This one is better.

```
  int loc = -1;
  while((loc = line.find("  ",loc+1)) != std::string::npos) //Two spaces here
  {
       line.replace(loc,2," "); //Single space in quotes
  }
  cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: I think that should be `while((loc = line.find("  ")) != std::string::npos)`.

Comment: @Fred - Why do I always forget the terminating conditions. :P

Comment: Hey, this is a O(n^2) solution. How about O(n)?

Comment: @Thomas - Just requires a small modification.

Comment: @Neo, just pushing for a better solution

Comment: @Thomas - I've already edited the answer which gives O(n) complexity.

Comment: @Neo, yes I saw it. I was responding to your earier comment.